# Is $(\Bbb N,\operatorname{LCM}(a,b))$ a monoid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Is $(\Bbb N,\operatorname{LCM}(a,b))$ a monoid?

Is it associative and does it have a neutral element?

Refer to answer below for my attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The neutral element cannot depend on elements: it is a global notion.

Moreover your problem is ill-posed: $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ is *not* $0$, though $0$ is a common multiple of all numbers, so   you question should be : Is $(\mathbf N^*, \operatorname{lcm})$ a monoid? 
The answer is yes: as you showed, it is associative,  and the neutral element is $1$.

Note that it is *not* a `regular` monoid: $\operatorname{lcm}(16,6)=\operatorname{lcm}(16,12)$.

Comment: What defines a regular monoid? Also where did I assume it was $0$?

Comment: Is your second paragraph assuming $\Bbb N=0,1,2,\dots$ rather than $\Bbb N=1,2,3,\dots$? E.g. Your $\Bbb N^*$ is my $\Bbb N$, just as my $\Bbb Z^+$ is your $\Bbb N^*$?

Comment: You misunderstood me: I wanted to point  there is a problem with $0$ if you take the whole of $\mathbf N$. The lcm of 0 and another element does not exist. As for a regular (commutative) monoid, it is a monoid in which the cancellation law holds: $a*b=a*c\Rightarrow b=c$. It allows to embed the monoid in a group (e.g. $\mathbf N\hookrightarrow \mathbf Z$.

Comment: OK I see. Normally $\mathbf N$ starts at $0$, and $\mathbf Z^+$ also starts at 0.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently it is poor practice to leave ambiguity by not using clear notation(from the wiki page) so this was my fault. It is recommended to never write $\Bbb N$ at all, rather $\Bbb N^0$ when it has $0$, and $\Bbb N^*$ when it does not.

Comment: In the divisibility order, $0$ is the greatest element, not the least.  So  in that sense we can still include $0$.

Comment: Generally it makes sense to include zero; one has $\operatorname{lcm}(a,0) = 0$ for all $a$.  Similarly $\gcd(a,0) = a$ for all $a$.

Answer (score 0):

The neutral element of each element is itself, since $\operatorname{lcm}(a,a)=a$ and also $\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c)=\operatorname{lcm}(a,\operatorname{lcm}(b,c))$, hence it is associative, thus $(\Bbb N, \operatorname{lcm}(a,b))$ is a monoid.

---

$\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c)=\operatorname{lcm}(a,\operatorname{lcm}(b,c))$

Proof

Answer (score 0):

In fact, we can add GCD and get a [lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)).

The set $\mathbb N := \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$ with the "divisibility" partial order
$$
a \; | \; b \Longleftrightarrow \exists k \big(ak=b\big)
$$
is a lattice.  Lattice operations $a \vee b$ and $a \wedge b$ are LCM and GCD, respectively.  The operations are associative.  And (as I said in a comment), $0$ is the greatest element, while $1$ is the least element.  So $0$ is the neutral element for $\wedge$; and $1$ is the neutral element for $\vee$.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand this answer. I haven't heard of a lattice before. I will go and read up on this and ask for when I have questions. Thank you!